# Probability space / Cartesian product

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ is a probability space, that $\Omega=\{0,2\} \times \{0,2\} $, and that $\mathscr{F}=2^{\Omega}.$ Is the following calculation completely correct?

$1=P(\Omega)=P(\bigcup\limits_{\omega \in \Omega }\{\omega\}) = \sum\limits_{\omega \in \Omega}P(\{\omega\})$.

The way the question is phrased suggests no but I cannot think of a reason. Isn't $\Omega=\{(0,0),(0,2),(2,0),(2,2)\}$?

The $\omega$s in $\Omega$ are countable (i.e, 4) and pairwise disjoint (you can take the intersection of any two of the $\omega$s and you will get the empty set). So Kolmogorov's 3rd axiom is satisfied (which I think is already implicit, since the problem says "Suppose $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ is a probability space ..."). Also, why does the problem mention $\mathscr{F}=2^{\Omega}$ (I am assuming this plays a role ...).

I apologize beforehand if the question is silly and appreciate any help/tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2^\Omega$ is the set of all functions that map $\Omega$ into $\{0,1\}$. It can also be shown that $2^\Omega$ has a one-to-one correspondence with the power set of $\Omega$. This means that when we define our probability measure $P: \mathscr{F} \to [0,1]$ we are defining a probability for any subset of $\Omega$. Naturally, $P(\emptyset) = 0$ and $P(\Omega) = 1$.

The calculation also appears correct for this example. We already know that $P(\Omega) = 1$. Certainly $\Omega$ is equal to the union of the singleton subsets of $\Omega$. And all these singleton sets are also disjoint.

Comment: Right, that's what I was thinking. But is there any way that the calculation is not correct? I just find interesting that the question is phrased as "Is the following calculation completely correct?"

Comment: Perhaps the question is trying to get you to think about it for other spaces. This calculation is correct for this space and it relies on the fact that our space $\Omega$ is countable.